# Front-end : html/css+javascript, Backend : perl

Tags: javascript, perl, frontend, backend

Want to create a web application *(using html/css + javascript)* that logs in to a linux based storage device, Process some logs of the storage device *(using perl)* and return the result to the web application.

**What/How** to use as a connector between them? And which one would be the simplest to do so?

Comment: This question is off-topic as being *“primarily opinion-based”* and is likely to be deleted. But take a look at [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CGI isn't recommended much these days. [Read this](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

As @Borodin already said, many possibilites here (and theyre really opinion based). I would to use:

1. [Poet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Poet) - as an really fantastic framework using Mason templating, builtin configuration system, caching, logging - fully Moose based. The drawback is - very small user-base and you will probably never got any answer to your Poet/Mason questions nowhere.
2. [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) - another nice web-framework, many plugins, active users.

Maybe your needs are different - check https://metacpan.org/ .

For the **how** part - quick guide:

```
#install your own perl - don't pollute he system's perl with new modules
\curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
#follow the instructions add line to .profile and 
source ~/.profile
perlbrew install perl-5.20.1
    #coffe break
perlbrew switch perl-5.20.1
perlbrew install-cpanm

#install the framework and all dependecies
cpanm Poet
#time for the tea ;)

#generate your skeleton app and start the server
poet new MyAppName
myappname/bin/run.pl
```

and you can connect to http://0:5000 to your working web-application and start the development.

Answer (score 0):

As you're going to use Perl anyway, I'd go with [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html).

Anyway, you're going to need a server - perhaps [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~falcone/HTTP-Server-Simple-0.50/lib/HTTP/Server/Simple.pm) would be enough for you.